# Can't edit such file in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Xcode 4.6.3 occasionally makes some file absolutely uneditable (see the pic for details). The contents remains unchanged, I just can't do anything with this file inside Xcode.

[image: xcode]

Comment: This is really about a bug in Xcode, not about programming.

Comment: That is a screenshot from a particularly old version of Xcode. Try updating, Xcode 5.1.1 was released today (April 11th 2014).

Comment: @Jasarien It seems that upgrading to latest version helped. I think you should post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Xcode is old (judging by the screenshot). You should update it. Xcode 5.1.1 was released on April 11th 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Few tips:

1. Open file in `Finder` -> Right click -> `Get Info`. Make sure you have write permissions.
2. Open file in `TextEditor` mac app, edit it and re-open in `Finder`
3. Create a new project, edit file in the new project and if the file is editable, try to move these files there.
4. If this project created from latest XCode and re-opening in the previous version then you should create project in Old Xcode and upgrade to the new one.

Hope it helps!